# I need to pause the execution till I get response from my database. How do i do it?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, java-threads

I am making an Android Java Application. I have a class with a function which uses Volley to get me 2D string array from my databse.
 Since I cannot return the string array from the function I created (Since I'm using volley),  I saved it in a static variable of another class.

In my main activity, I call the class which gets me the string array and it assigns it to the static variable.

The problem is that before my string array is received by the classes, the 2D array is used by my main activity and since the string array is undefined. It gives me a null pointer exception.

I need to let the initialization of string array first and then have it be used my main acitivty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my function that calls an API return an empty or null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Comment: can you provide me the code for a bit that you are facing issue with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the initialization of string array should be done on **onResponse()**
if you have made the String array initialization in the main thread you will get the error that you have mentioned above. You should only invoke the string array on the volley thread only.

Comment: I have initialized the array in volley on response only, and passed the array to a static class variable. in main thread I only access that variable

Comment: are you passing the static class variable using interface?

Comment: No, im getting the static variable directly

Comment: that's why you  get the error directly do it through an interface method

Comment: I ran it my main activity yesterday and it worked

Comment: make possible with a low net speed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239693/discussion-between-viren-joshi-and-ajay-k-s).